# Expanding div based on cursor location on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this guy awesome website, and and he has this this two pictures sliding left and right depending on mouse location.
As you can see if cursor is right, right part expands, if it is left it expand left part.

Here is website: http://www.adhamdannaway.com/

Can anyone explain me how to do this, or is there any tutorial or something?

Comment: see the "animateFace()" function in script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a very rough proof of concept you might like playing with:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkj0ufbb/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>

body {
    margin:0px;
}
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
#left, #right {
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
#left {
    left:0%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
#right {
    left:50%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;
}

jQuery(function($){
    var prev = null;
    $('#wrapper').bind('mousemove', function(e){
        var target = e.pageX / $(this).width();
        var duration = 0;
        if(prev == null)
        {
            prev = e.pageX;
            duration = Math.abs(e.pageX - $(this).width() / 2)
        }
        else
        {
            duration = Math.abs(e.pageX - prev);
        }
        $('#left').stop(true, false).animate({
            'width': (1 - target) * 100 + '%'
        }, duration, 'linear');
        $('#right').stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': (1 - target) * 100 + '%',
            'width': target * 100 + '%'
        }, duration, 'linear');
    }).bind('mouseout', function(){
        prev = null;
        $('#left').stop(true, false).animate({
            'width': '50%'
        }, 400);
        $('#right').stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '50%',
            'width': '50%'
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

I didn't really look into how the referenced site did it, but this was the first sort of concept that came to mind.